# Google Apps Script: my function of copy,paste and delete doesn't yet execute all the rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help me the experts!

What I would like to do?

1. Copy the whole rows that contains value of 'Paid'
2. Paste the rows to the last row of another sheet.
3. Delete the rows

However, after I use codes as below I copy, paste, and delete only half of the rows that contains value of 'Paid, but if I delete the code 'studentInfoSheet.deleteRow(i);', it copies and pastes all the rows that I want but not delete the rows.

Here is my code of Google Apps Script:

1. Declaration:

```
function clearAndPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var studentInfoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("studentInfo");
  var database = ss.getSheetByName("database");
  var paymentStatus = "Paid";
  var lastRow = studentInfoSheet.getLastRow() +1;
  var foundRecord = false;
```

2. Execution

```
  for( var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++ ) {
    if(studentInfoSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == paymentStatus) {
      var getCopyRange = studentInfoSheet.getRange('A' + i + ':E' + i);
      var nextRow = database.getLastRow()+1;
      getCopyRange.copyTo(database.getRange(nextRow, 1));
      studentInfoSheet.deleteRow(i);
    } 
  }
if(foundRecord == false) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No New Paid Account Yet");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found one of my solution:

- Instead of using delete function, using clear instead because if I delete a row instantly, half of rows would move up and won't count on i++;

If you can make any shorten codes, please comment guys :).

```
function clearAndPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var studentInfoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("studentInfo");
  var database = ss.getSheetByName("database");
  var paymentStatus = "Paid";
  
  var lastRow = studentInfoSheet.getLastRow() +1;
  var foundRecord = false;

  for( var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++ ) {
    if(studentInfoSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == paymentStatus) {
      var getCopyRange = studentInfoSheet.getRange('A' + i + ':E' + i);
      var nextRow = database.getLastRow()+1;
      getCopyRange.copyTo(database.getRange(nextRow, 1));
      getCopyRange.clear();
    } 
  }
  for( var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++ ) {
    if(studentInfoSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == "") {
      studentInfoSheet.deleteRow(i);
    } 
  }
if(foundRecord == false) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No New Paid Account Yet");
}
}
```